# MySQL - If a user can Create a view, do they really need ALTER and DROP?

Tags: mysql, privileges

I don't want to give DROP or ALTER access to a reporting userid in the DB. Is there a big drawback to allowing the CREATE VIEW and not giving ALTER or DROP to the user? or am I trying to be too security conscious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do they need to regularly or urgently alter or drop? If so, give them the permissions.

If not, let them go via a formal channel to request the change.

Always give the least privilege possible, that's not "too security conscious"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jon. I always struggle with the balance between security and everything else.